# How do I create an averages row at the bottom of a Crosstab

Tags: jasper-reports, pivot-table, crosstab

I have a crosstab that prints data like this

```
univNr    tst1   tst2    reslt    prak    dnp
123       45     75      Pass     51      60
124       32     40      Fail     39      45
125       81     85      Dist     90      79
126       49     70      Pass     53      62
127       60     65      Pass     53      69
```

How do I add a averages column at the bottom so that it looks like this

```
univNr    tst1   tst2    reslt    prak    dnp
123       45     75      Pass     51      60
124       32     40      Fail     39      45
125       81     85      Dist     90      79
126       49     70      Pass     53      62
127       60     65      Pass     52      69
Average:  53     67               57      63
```

**Extra Info:**

I'm using *iReport 5.5* to create reports for *JasperReports Server 5.0.1*

The data given to the crosstab to pivot looks something like this

```
univNr    module    modVal
123       tst1      45
123       tst2      75
123       result    Pass
123       prak      51
123       dnp       60
124       tst1      32
124       tst2      45
124       result    Fail
124       prak      39
124       dnp       45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've Tried many solutions and spoken to jasper support, it Appears there is no Way to do this since You can't work out the average of a string field.

What I ended up doing is modifying the Query to put all the string values of "modVal" in a separate column "result" so that I can make "modVal" and Int, and then be able to work out the averages / totals